# How to perform multiple operations concurrently on DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following background service running:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                    {
                        DataContext dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                        var tasks = new List<Task>();
                        tasks.Add(siteA.ProcessSchedule(SportLeagues.MLB, logger, dbContext));
                        tasks.Add(siteB.ProcessSchedule(SportLeagues.MLB, logger, dbContext));
                        //....more of same task
                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await Task.Delay(0, stoppingToken);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I constantly get this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
    A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed.
```

I can refactor and create a `dbContext` for each task, however I would prefer to use a single dbContext if possible.

I also tried adding my dbContext as transient:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("db");
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

But this did not help.  Am I creating my dbContext in an incorrect way? Or is the best approach to create a new `dbContext` for each task?  For more context, this is a constantly running background task, it takes a second to complete and it will have around 20 tasks.  It sounds pretty inefficient to be creating and destroying 20 `dbContext` every second, along with having to do 20 `dbContext` saves.

Comment: If you are doing that work continuously, you don't need to create and destroy contexts, you could just hold on to them and re-use them. And yes, you need one for each task you are running in parallel, they are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your design. For one thing, `DbContext` is not thread-safe, and hence cannot be used from multiple tasks or threads safely.

`DbContext` is also tracking objects (unless `AsNoTracking()` and similar methods are used on all query operations). If you keep using the same `DbContext` instance for a long period of time, then it will take a lot of memory, and its performance might reduce as well.

On the other hand, instantiating a new `DbContext` should be a cheap operation, unless it is bloated by containing too many tables - that would be a design flaw of a different kind.

All these considerations point into direction of instantiating a new `DbContext` in every operation that needs it, rather than reusing instances. If subsequent operations need to communicate state, then reusing a `DbContext` is one of the less favorable solutions to that end.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!  Subsequent operations will not be affected by states, each task affects a unique table in `dbContext` and has no bearing on other tasks, so I will be creating a different dbContext for each.

Comment: why cant microsoft just make dbcontext multithread safe??? this is complete bs

Comment: @Saylent For the same reason databases implement isolation. You don't mix multiple threads of execution, multiple commands, and multiple persistent processes together, unless there is a serious problem with how you defined operations on persistence. Think for yourself: What would be the operation that accesses the same DbContext from multiple threads, knowing that DbContext is UnitOfWork and Repository?

Answer (score 0):

Activating MARS in your Connection String should solve your problem.

like: "Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;**MultipleActiveResultSets=True**"

Read This Microsoft Document For More Info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Comment: It doesn't solves *this* problem! MARS doesn't make queries parallel. MARS allows `Entity framework` to keep more than 1 `DataReader` open at a time, but their *Read* operations will still happen after each other. In this answer you can find sources and details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74770157/can-i-use-mars-with-ef-core-to-retrieve-details-on-in-a-foreach/78017962#78017962