# Can I use MARS with EF Core to retrieve details on in a foreach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure that the current implementation of our DAL is correct and I think that the number of connections to the DB is low with respect to what it should be.

I've noticed that there's no [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) inside the connection string

and when I try to perform multple calls on the same repository I got

> System.InvalidOperationException:A second operation was started on
> this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is
> usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
> instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading
> issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

This means that I cannot open use the same repository for example executing an operation in parallel (for example getting some details?)

for example

```
foreach(var i in mainProducts) // retrieved from EF with a .ToListAsync
{
    i.Details = await repo.GetDetailsFromIdAsync(i.Id);
}
```

I know that sometime i can just return a single object from the query, but there're some cases where I can't

Thanks

Comment: Why not get all the values you want with a single query though? SQL Server `WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3)` vs EF `.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)`

Comment: as I wrote,sometime it can happen some other when I need to perform more  complex calls, i need to do another query, and was wondering why I can't in parallel

Comment: `DbContext` isn't designed for being used in parallel and will break if you try, it's nothing to do with MARS. If you need to run multiple queries to the same database at the same time, you need multiple instances of your context. For that, you can inject a `DbContextFactory` instead and grab as many as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of MARS if you change the code:

- MARS doesn't make queries parallel (see later),
- assigning navigation property `i.Details` instead of loading it is a bad idea: if `mainProducts` are observed by EF *Change Tracking* and `Details` are not, an assignment to the property can cause side effects like update/insert.

You should load it with `Include()` which retrieves the same data from the DB using only 1 query as oppose to the current foreach approach which executes huge amount of queries.

In ***Single Query*** mode the `Include()` works as a **left join**. You get all the data with 1 query.

In ***Split Query*** mode (recommended) the `Include()` works as an advanced *Explicit Loading*, it fires:

- 1 query to get `mainProducts`
- 1 query to get the related `Details` of the `mainProducts`.

*Split Query* indeed uses MARS to skip the [internal buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#internal-buffering-by-ef).

Point of interest:

- [Explicit Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit)
- [Examples of Projection (recommended) vs Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77681489/sql-linq-with-sub-entities/77699320#77699320)

---

**MARS vs. Parallel operation**:

MARS setup (if supported) is there to spare memory, not to parallelize the queries. Hence, with or without MARS the same number of queries will occur with the same number of connections opened & closed (taken from the pool, returned to the pool), each after each, non-parallel.

The only difference in the setup is: When MARS is disabled, the 2nd query execution forces the 1st query (the reader of the query) to be closed. To keep the result data of this 1st query EF Core needs to iterate the whole and store it internally (creates a copy in memory). Then the 3rd query forces the 2nd to close, and so on. When MARS is enabled, all queries stay open, waiting to be iterated by user code (`ToList()`/`foreach`/`Find()`) = none of their data was buffered to memory by EF.

The code in the question as is wouldn't gain from MARS, as there is no multiple active queries at the same time:

- the query of `mainProducts` was completed before the `foreach` (by `ToListAsync()`),
- each `GetDetailsFromIdAsync()` completes (by `Find()` I assume) before the next one is fired