# SQL Linq with sub-entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

Let's say you have tables `Customer` and `Purchases` and you want to return a DTO of all customers from the city of Knuffingen and their purchaes in 2023.

```
var customers = context.Customer
  .Where(c => c.City = "Knuffingen")
  .ToList();
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
  var purchases = customer.Purchases
    .Where(p => p.Year == 2023)
    .ToList();
  yield return new DTO(customer, purchases);
}
```

would obviously a bad idea because every loop iteration would query a new request against the database.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
var customers = context.Customer
  .Where(c => c.City = "Knuffingen")
  .ToList();
var customerIds = customer
  .Select(c => c.Id)
  .ToList();
var purchases = context.Purchases
  .Where(p => customerIds.Contains(p.CustomerId)
    && p.Year == 2023)
  .ToList();
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
  var customerPurchases = purchases
    .Where(p => p.CustomerId == customer.Id)
    .ToList()
  yield return new DTO(customer, customerPurchases);
}
```

but that needs to take into consideration the max amount of query parameters and if necessary split up the query into multiple segments.

I was wondering if there was a better way, for example like this:

```
var customerQueryable = context.Customers
  .Where(c => c.City == "Knuffingen");
var customers = customerQueryable
  .ToList();
var purchases = customerQueryable
  .SelectMany(c => c.Purchases
    .Where(p => p.Year == 2023))
  .ToList();
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
  var customerPurchases = purchases
    .Where(p => p.CustomerId == customer.Id)
    .ToList()
  yield return new DTO(customer, customerPurchases);
}
```

but if you have more things than just purchases dependent on the `Customer` entity and your initial filter is a bit more complex I'm not sure it wouldn't put a bigger strain on the database to query all the customers over and over and over again.

Comment: [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)

Comment: needs to take into consideration the max amount of query parameters* -- No, because Contains is translated as an `IN` statement with constants (which may cause other issues). That said, always do things like this by projecting data directly into a dto.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, querying customers over and over is performance heavy and unnecessary.

What you achieved with your 2nd and 3rd example is a split query. You can do that better if you go with your 1st example and change only the execution (from lazy loading to eager) with either:

- `Include()` - loads related table data in left join manner,
- filtered include (good but sensitive),
- projection.

And you need to fix the where clause to check if the Customers also purchased in 2023 and not just live in Knuffingen:

```
var matchingCustomers = context.Customers
    .Where(c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(p => p.Year == 2023))
```

---

### Solution with `.Include`:

The actual number of database roundtrips (query executions) will depend on `QuerySplittingBehavior`. A join sounds very memory heavy because of [cartesian explosion](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/cartesian-explosion-problem-in-3-1/) but using `AsSplitQuery()` makes it perform good while keeps the code clean and readable.

```
var matchingCustomers = context.Customers
    .Where(c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(p => p.Year == 2023))
    .Include(c => c.Purchases)
    .AsSplitQuery(); // +1 roundtrip per Include but no cartesian-explosion

foreach (var c in matchingCustomers)
{
    var purchases = c.Purchases
        .Where(p => p.Year == 2023)
        .ToList(); // no roundtrip to DB
    yield return new DTO(c, purchases);
}
```

To reduce iterations, you can skip `ToList()` ([See IQueryable streaming explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946207/does-foreach-cause-repeated-linq-execution)) and continue directly with foreach or replace the foreach with a select:

```
    .Select(c => new DTO(c, c.Purchases.Where(p => p.Year == 2023).ToList()));
```

---

### Solution with Projection:

**Both above** (foreach/select) **will select all columns of the filtered `Customers` and all columns of their `Purchases`** in order to provide all necessary data for the DTO constructor. EF preprocessors cannot assume which property is really consumed by the constructor [see examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115690/ef-core-queries-all-columns-in-sql-when-mapping-to-object-in-select).

If you checked the *examples* of the link above, you already know how **to fasten up the query: turn your select into a projection**:

```
Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> purchasedIn2023 = p => p.Year == 2023;

return context.Customers
    .Where(c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(purchasedIn2023))
    .AsSplitQuery() // should work the same: +1 roundtrip per Include (not per customer) but please test what query is generated
    .Select(c => new DTO()
    {
        CustomerName = c.Name,
        // projections ignores includes, all (customer related) purchases can be accessed here
        TotalCost = c.Purchases.Where(purchasedIn2023).Sum(p => p.CostAmount)
    });
```

With this, only the projected columns are retrieved from the database (`c.Name, p.CostAmount`).

I have to mention: Not every Linq function can be transpiled, e.g. `Average()` will work, `string.Join()` will not. Check [supported aggregate methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities#aggregate-methods).

---

### Solution with filtered include:

Since we cannot use projection and filtered include together, we are back to having a list and retrieving all columns of Customer and Purchase from DB. The bright side: this only loads the necessary Purchases. Choose this when you need most columns from both tables but very few Purchases of each Customer, otherwise use projection.

```
var matchingCustomers = context.Customers
    .Where(c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(purchasedIn2023))
    .Include(c => c.Purchases.Where(purchasedIn2023))
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToList();

foreach (var c in matchingCustomers)
{
    // c.Purchases contains only the ones made in 2023 IF no EF fix-ups happened (no purchases has been loaded earlier - can be achieved with transient service call)
    // change the constructor to accept ICollection instead of List
    yield return new DTO(c, c.Purchases);
}
```

You can use further filtering, for example take the 5 most expensive purchase only:

```
    .Include(c => c.Purchases.Where(purchasedIn2023).OrderByDescending(p => p.CostAmount).Take(5))
```

---

**As for your 2nd question**

"what happens if there is more dependency to finding Customers than just Purchases" I see 2 approaches:

1. You have only 1 or 2 customer filtering logic, so you decide to keep each logic inside a separate function and you modify the Where clause, extend the Include or Select as necessary.
2. You have a lot of different filtering logic, so you decide to introduce *Predicate* (filter expression) to your function.

   ```
    IEnumerable<DTO> GetCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, Customer>> filter)
    {
        return context.Customers
            .Where(filter)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .Select(c => new DTO()
            {
                CustomerName = c.Name,
                // I changed the select to be independent from the predicate
                LastOrder = c.Purchases.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First()
            });
    }

    // call like:
    GetCustomers(c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(p => p.Year == 2023))
   ```

   And this can go very deep in terms of reusability:

   ```
    IEnumerable<DTO> GetCustomers(
        Expression<Func<Customer, Customer>> filter,
        Expression<Func<Customer, DTO>> selector)
    {
        return context.Customers
            .Where(filter)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .Select(selector);
            // no need to call AsEnumerable(), it is cast implicitly
            // however return ICollection or List if the result iterated more than once!
    }

    ICollection<DTO> GetCustomers(
        Expression<Func<Customer, Customer>> filter,
        Func<IQueryable<Customer>, IQueryable<Customer>> include)
    {
        var customers = include(context.Customers)
            .Where(filter)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .ToList();
    }

    // call like:
    GetCustomers(
        filter: c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(p => p.Year == 2023)),
        selector: c => new DTO() { CustomerName = c.Name, TotalCost = c.Purchases.Sum(p => p.CostAmount) });

    GetCustomers(
        filter: c => c.City == "Knuffingen" && c.Purchases.Any(p => p.Year == 2023)),
        include: c => c.Include(c => c.Purchases.Where(p => p.Year == 2023))
                     // possible future relation
                     //.Include(c => c.PersonalInfo.Where(i => i.BornYear >= 2005))
    );
   ```

Comment: "// due to filtered include c.Purchases contains only the ones made in 2023"

Question: If I ever need the full list of purchases for that customer: How do I re-query that relationship property?

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena I need to fix that statement, filtered incudes only works if this is a transient request and not any purchases has been loaded yet (otherwise they are 'fixed-up"), plus I now remember: unfortunately projections are ignoring includes. I will edit my solution to include this and to answer your follow-up question.

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena I wanted to avoid *Query Splitting* and *Entity Loading* to the discussion because of the depth, but indeed there is no solution without them. Let me know if you have some question.